# Margin-right property not working?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create table which looks like below:

[image]

I have tried using margin-right property ,and also border spacing ,colspan but not able to achieve it!

Here is my link to codepen:https://codepen.io/saisree/pen/jwwwEZ

```
 <tr >
     <td  style="padding-top:10px;"colspan="2"class=" fixed text-center">
       <span class=" border6 bold pull-left">2210 924-16(267)  </span><span class="boxed1"></span></tr>
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This question is familiar...did you already asked this before?

Comment: Yes ,but i'm not able to achieve it after using all properties suggested!

Comment: missing a </td>

Comment: @Swellar indeed.

Comment: No i have it in my main source code!

Comment: I remember cause I think I edited a similar question

Comment: Since this is just the same as your previous question, wouldn't it gather the same suggested properties?

Comment: Actually i was hoping for more possible options ! Because the previous ones didn't work!

Comment: And where is that previous question? You should at least link to it, so that we can see what was already suggested, and don’t have to tell you the same stuff again ... Please don’t say you already deleted it?

Comment: Apart from that, you don’t want to be messing with margins on table cells, that is bound to end in chaos IMHO. You want to use colspan for this. But looking at your codepen, I don’t even see what the actual issue is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need two `td`s  in each `tr`. In the first 4 rows you apply the attribute `colspan="2"` to the second `td` tag, in the rows after that you apply  `colspan="2"` to the first `td` tag. That's basically all. So actually, there are three TDs in each row, but as each row has a td with a colspan, you only see two in each row.

The width will depend  on the contents by default, but you can use width settings for the tds of course. You can *not*  use margins on `td`s.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-width: 35%;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td colspan="2" ;>BBB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td colspan="2" ;>BBB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td colspan="2" ;>BBB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td colspan="2" ;>BBB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" ;>CCC</td>
    <td>DDD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" ;>CCC</td>
    <td>DDD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" ;>CCC</td>
    <td>DDD</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```